With "Load file content in memory" load multiple files from Azure Blob storage dynamically
I am using "Load file content in memory" input load into postgresql database. I have generated SAS, created the variable, edited the kettle.properties file with SAS path. All working as expected, the file is loading into POstgresql Database. It's a RTF file, I am able to copy the file content as one column with a single file.
My problem, there are 100s of file in Azure Blob and want them to load into the same table, which I can not create 100s of variables to load each file, as it may varies. Is there any method which I can use to load all files at the same time into one table. The file is RTF file, the entire file content will be a single column in the database.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
